# phpBB doesn't find mysql before installation

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I 'm trying to install phpBB 3. I have already set up my webserver and MySQL and tested them. But in the Database configuration of phpBB there is no MySQL as Database type. I can see only MS SQL Server. It is like I have not MySQL installed. Why is this happening? Can someone help please?

Comment: Does PHP show MySQL support in `phpinfo()`?

Answer (score 2):

verify with

```
phpinfo();
```

that MySQL extension is loaded , server is up and running.
[Rebuilding config file](http://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/rebuilding-your-configphp-file/)
Try following this basic guide http://www.phpbb.com/community/docs/INSTALL.html#quickinstall

are you usng any other webserver other than Apache??

Comment: Thanks. I ll try this. It is up and running, I checked this!

Comment: The config.php that downloaded with phpBB is empty! There is nothing to change! Any idea?

Comment: read the *Configuration File* section into the guide, the config file for phpbb3 is generated when you install it.

Comment: But this is my problem. I want to install it with MySql but I can't. There is no MySql option in Database Configuration through the installation.

Comment: I 'm using Apache webserver and with phpinfo I verified that mysql exists. Thanks for your time, but I quit trying this cause I didn't find a solution. I can't figure it out. As for rebuilding config.php I think that there is no point, cause it is not even configured once. phpBB is not installed. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: well the link has the basic variables used by phpbb to connect to database. try at phpbb3 forum, might be somekind of bug somewhere..

Comment: Well, I found what the problem was! It was about mysal installation. An older php.ini was held in win/system32 folder! When I put my new one everything went fine! Again thanks for your time!